# TFS 2015 Version Numbering By Branch

Tags: git, msbuild, versioning, tfs-2015

I am creating a Continuous Integration build definition against against a Git repository in TFS 2015. The definition is configured with triggers against both the "master" and "develop" branches.

Based on the branch that triggers a build, version numbers need to be incremented as follows:

**develop branch:**
major.minor.(build+1)
ie; Maintains current major & minor versions, increments the build number only

**master branch:**
major.(minor+1).0
ie; Maintains the major version, increments minor version and resets the build number for subsequent builds on the develop branch

On completion of a successful build, the respective branches need to have a tag (label) applied to indicate the version that was built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research I've resolved to achieve this by using two build definitions (master & dev) and a PowerShell script which is executed against the master build definition to dynamically update dev.

Since this may be useful to others in future, here's my PowerShell script...

```
# Gather environment variables from TFS...
$buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$tfsCollectionUri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$teamProjectId = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID
# Enable "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" in the "master" build's Options
$accessToken = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
# Declare "DevBuildDefinitionId" in the "master" build's Variables and populate with the id of the "dev" build
$devDefinitionId = $env:DevBuildDefinitionId

# Construct the new build number format based on the latest build number...
$parts = $buildNumber.split(".")
$buildNumberFormat = ($parts[0] + "." + $parts[1] + "`$(Rev:.r)")

Write-Host 
Write-Host "New Dev build number format: $buildNumberFormat"
Write-Host 

$uri = "$($tfsCollectionUri)$teamProjectId/_apis/build/definitions/$($devDefinitionId)?api-version=2.0"

#Retrieve the dev build definition...
try {
    $definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" }

    # Modify the version number format...
    $definition.buildNumberFormat = $buildNumberFormat

    # Update the build definition
    try {
        $body = ConvertTo-Json $definition -Depth 1000
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" } -Body $body -ContentType application/json

        Write-Host 
        Write-Host "Dev build definition successfully updated"
        Write-Host 
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host 
        Write-Host "Failed to update the Dev build definition..."
        Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
        Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
        Write-Host 
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host 
    Write-Host "Failed to retrieve the Dev build definition..."
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
    Write-Host 
}
```

Note that, in order for this to work, you will need to modify the "Project Build Collection Service" permissions slighly to avoid receiving a security exception when the update is requested. To do this, navigate "Build definitions" list, click the dropdown next to the dev build, select "Security", scroll to the users section and set the "Edit build definition" permission to allow

Answer (score 0):

This kind of complex version number setting can't achieved in a single TFS build definition for now.

TFS can't  increase the build number based on which branch trigger the build. It's using `$(Rev:.rr)` to ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value is **incremented by one**. More details, please refer this two  threads [Specify general build definition settings](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general)   & [vNext Build Awesomeness – Managing Version Numbers](http://incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/)

For your situation, you may have to create two build definition correspond *develop* and *master* branch. Then manually increase the minor value in develop build definition or use a powershell script to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrick.

This sounds like something that should be a fairly common requirement, do you anticipate that this is something which may be changing in TFS15?

Comment: The news and release of production,  you could follow https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/news-overview-vs.aspx. Not have related update for now. Besides , I'm a little confused with your structure of version number. Why the minor version should be increased just when a simply build triggered  on  master branch instead of using a common structure `(Major version).(Minor version).(Revision number).(Build number)`  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166215/when-do-you-change-your-major-minor-patch-version-number

Comment: Not sure I follow your question, the schema we're using is a standard Semantic Versioning system...

Major version would imply a significant change to the application (for instance; something that will break backwards compatibility)
Minor version would imply a smaller change (for instance; an improvement/refinement in existing functionality which maintains backwards compatibility)
Build/Revision number is used to denote a patch or, in our case, a test version leading up to a new Minor